# Empty 3x placeholder images does implies a detrimental on the UX performance of an iPhone 6 plus?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, assets, iphone-6-plus

Xcode 6 has created on my behalf 3x placeholders.

I just wanted to make sure that by leaving empty my 400 assets (at the moment) will not impact the performance on a iPhone 6 plus.

Comment: There's no reason why it would have any serious effect. At worst it will try and load the 3x assets and when it doesn't find any it would just load the 2x assets. This is an assumption, and it may end up showing nothing if it can't find the 3x assets, but either way performance shouldn't worry you.

Comment: There's only one way to find out: test it. My guess is that the difference would be negligible but a guess is no substitute for data.